# Title not translate in other language

Tags: select, typo3, multilingual, typoscript

I use typo3 6.2.4

I need to translate the title in other language For now, if I'm in Frontend with the language "Deutsch", it's the title of the language "Français" who is displayed. My configuration for my three language :

```
config.linkVars = L
config.uniqueLinkVars = 2
config.sys_language_overlay = 0
config.language = fr
config.locale_all = fr_FR
config.htmlTag_langKey = fr-FR
config.sys_language_uid = 0
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 0

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.language = de
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.locale_all = de_DE
config.htmlTag_langKey = de-DE
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 1

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN
config.htmlTag_langKey = en-EN
config.sys_language_uid = 2
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 2
[end]
```

My select :

```
  page.10 >
  page.10 = CONTENT
  page.10.table = pages
  page.10.select {

    pidInList = this
    orderBy = sorting
  }
  page.10.renderObj = COA
  page.10.renderObj {

    10 = TEXT
    10.field = title
    10.wrap = <div class="titleFormation">|</div>
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp.languageTitle >
temp.languageTitle = CONTENT
temp.languageTitle.table = pages

[globalVar = GP:L = 1] || [globalVar = GP:L = 2]
temp.languageTitle.select {
  join = pages_language_overlay ON(pages.uid=pages_language_overlay.pid)
  andWhere {
    data = TSFE:sys_language_uid
    wrap = pages_language_overlay.sys_language_uid=|
  }
  pidInList = this
  orderBy = sorting
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
temp.languageTitle.select {
  pidInList = this
  orderBy = sorting
}
[global]
```

We need to do that because in the DB SQL, the title in the other pages are not in the table "pages" but in the table "pages_language_overlay".

```
  page.10 >
  page.10 < temp.languageTitle
  page.10.renderObj = COA
  page.10.renderObj {

    10 = TEXT
    10.field = title
    10.wrap = <div class="titleFormation">|</div>
  }
```

And now the title is translate in the good language.